# .net mvc returning duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I've got an ajax/json call that is returning the ***correct number*** of records, but they are all the ***same record***, the first record.

SQL View:

```
ALTER view [dbo].[v_EMS_BM_Organization_Detail] as
select a.OrgID
,   a.Organization
,   a.inactive
,   b.buID
,   b.BusinessUnit
,   count(distinct c.Budget) Budgets
,   count(distinct d.BEMS) People
from t_EMS_BM_Organization a
left join t_EMS_BM_Business_Unit b
on a.OrgID = b.OrgID
left join t_EMS_BM_Budget c
on b.buID = c.buID
left join t_EMS_BM_Person d
on c.Budget = d.Budget
group by a.OrgID
,   a.Organization
,   a.inactive
,   b.buID
,   b.BusinessUnit
GO
```

When querying in SQL Server:

```
select *
from v_EMS_BM_Organization_Detail
where OrgID= 6
```

Returns:

```
OrgID   Organization    inactive    buID    BusinessUnit    Budgets People
6       E3001       0       27      Manufacturing Services Staff    1   5
6       E3001       0       43      BASN    1   0
6       E3001       0       45      Special Assignment  1   0
```

My Model:

```
namespace EMSBM.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class v_EMS_BM_Organization_Detail
    {
        public int OrgID { get; set; }
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> inactive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> buID { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Budgets { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> People { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult OrgDetails(int ID)
{
    List<v_EMS_BM_Organization_Detail> orgDetail = new List<v_EMS_BM_Organization_Detail>();

    orgDetail = db.v_EMS_BM_Organization_Detail.Where(x => x.OrgID == ID).OrderBy(x => x.BusinessUnit).ToList();

    return this.Json(new
    {
        Result = (from obj in orgDetail
                  select new
                  {
                      OrgID = obj.OrgID
                      ,
                      Organization = obj.Organization
                      ,
                      inactive = obj.inactive
                      ,
                      buID = obj.buID
                      ,
                      BusinessUnit = obj.BusinessUnit
                      ,
                      Budgets = obj.Budgets
                      ,
                      People = obj.People
                  })
    });
}
```

My Ajax/Json call:

```
$('#organization-table-body').delegate('tr', 'click', function () {
    var OrgID = $(this).attr('id');
    OrgID = OrgID.substr(2, OrgID.length);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/OrganizationDetail/OrgDetails',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ID: OrgID }),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#org-detail-body').empty();
            var html = '';
            $.each(data['Result'], function (i, item) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    $('#org-name').html(item.Organization +' Details');
                    $('#OrgID').val(OrgID);

                    $('#btn-active-status').removeClass('btn-primary');
                    $('#btn-active-status').removeClass('btn-danger');
                    if (item.inactive == true) {
                        $('#btn-active-status').html('Activate Organization');
                        $('#btn-active-status').addClass('btn-primary');
                    } else {
                        $('#btn-active-status').html('Deactivate Organization');
                        $('#btn-active-status').addClass('btn-danger');
                    }
                }
                html += '<tr id="tr' + item.buID + '" class="cursor-pointer"><td>' + item.BusinessUnit + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Budgets + '</td><td>' + item.People + '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#org-detail-body').html(html);
            $('#org-detail-div').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert(ex.responseText);
        }
    });
```

When passing 6 like in the sql server query above I get three records, this is correct. But all three records are only the first record:

```
Business Unit   Budgets     People
BASN            1           0
BASN            1           0
BASN            1           0
```

When debugging in VS 2012 I only get the first record duplicated the correct X number of times no matter what ID I pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to the lack of a primary key on your view. The method EF is trying to use to identify rows uniquely is failing.

It looks like you're using Database First and that model class is generated code? If so, go and look at it in the model browser. EF will have guessed (usually very badly) at which columns it should use to build a primary key. It includes columns in the key if it knows that they cannot be `NULL` and excludes columns if it isn't sure.

If you like you can create a surrogate key for the table using `ROW_NUMBER()`, or you can use existing columns. Either way, to provide hints to EF on which columns it includes in the key you should wrap the column in either `ISNULL()` (to force inclusion) or `NULLIF()` (to force exclusion).

There is a tutorial provided on all this here: http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/